# Check if part of string matches regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to validate strings according to various regular expressions; however, if whitespace characters get added to the **end** of the string, they do not get flagged anymore.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(literal.Value.ToString().ToLower(), @"^\+?[0-9\-\(\)\.\/]{8,20}$")
{
    //Logic
}
```

In the following piece of code; the X-value gets flagged but the Z-value does not.

```
string x = "0337350670"; // Gets flagged
string z = "0337350670     "; // Does not get flagged
```

Should I change my regular expression or is there a way to validate against a part of the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just `Trim` your string to remove trailing whitespaces from both sides.

Also, many special regex characters aren't special anymore inside a character class (`-` still is, but is escaped if you put it like so: `[...-]`).

```
Regex.IsMatch(literal.Value.ToString().ToLower().Trim(),
              @"^\+?[0-9()./-]{8,20}$"
```

Removing `^$` would work too, but be aware this would allow strings composed of more than 20 digits in a row: you don't check the maximum length anymore (anything *containing* `[0-9()./-]{8}` would match).

Comment: What would happen if I had something like this "1283712323   327462387462"? Would the trimmed string become "1283712323327462387462"?

Comment: Nope, `Trim` is designed for removing only trailing whitespaces: see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I like the addition of saying that removing the $ would allow strings of 20+ digits; because this is a key factor here. Your method suits best!

Answer (score 3):

Removing the `^` and `$` from the regular expression will allow the expression to match anywhere in the string.

Comment: Here you also need to add `*` to start and end, don't you?

Comment: I actually checked it, that is not needed, works if you remove the ^ and $.

Comment: +1 Removing the `$` is the fastest way. @Matthijs Just a sidenote though, `"0337350670sometext"` would also be flagged, if you only want to allow whitespace at the end, you could use `"^\+?[0-9\-\(\)\.\/]{8,20}\s*$"`

Comment: "0337350670sometext" would indeed get flagged, which is why this isn't a suitable answer for me; look at the Trim option proposed by Robin instead.

Comment: @Matthijs You did ask for a partial string match!

Comment: @phuzi I asked for a way to match if part of the string would match the entire regular expression; could probably have clarified more. Using your fix, a key factor of the regular expression (being numbers with 8-20 digits) would not be satisfied.

Comment: @Veikedo No, by default a regular expression will match anywhere inside the string. `^` and `$` are just other symbols that match the start and end of the string similar to how \b matches word boundaries etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `$` end of string character from the end and add `.*`:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(literal.Value.ToString().ToLower(), @"^\+?[0-9\-\(\)\.\/]{8,20}.*")
{
    //Logic
}
```

Now it will match both: [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yN8cI5)